# Work colleague keeps on asking too many questions

Tags: colleagues

One of my work colleagues who is a nice person keeps on asking me work related questions. I am starting to get irritated by the number of questions she is asking on regular bases, especially when I am busy with other tasks and stressed out.

How can I tell her in a nice way to stop doing this?

Comment: Are these appropriate questions?  Does the amount of questions indicate that your colleague doesn't have the skills to perform her job?  Are you answering these questions fully, or showing her how to find out for herself?

Comment: Welcome to every job ever. If you are good at what you do, this is the price you pay. Just tell them you are busy.

Answer (score 0):

Stop answering too many questions.

Start teaching her how she can find the answers by herself.  You can do this by working through the problems with her, or suggesting people she could ask, or where to look for the answers.

If these questions/answers are in email, just forward your prior answers with a short amendment, according to the case in question.